# Creating conditional sub dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe.  How do I create sub dataframes based on a continous condition in a column?  For example, in the below dataframe, I want to create a separate dataframe for each occurrence of continuous "1s" in column B.  So, in this example, the desired output would be three separate dataframes for rows 1 & 2, 4, and 6-9.  Thank you.

```
level_1 = ['A', 'B']
data = [['a1', 1], ['a2', 1],['a3', 0], ['a4', 0],['a1', 1], ['a5', 0],['a6', 1], ['a7', 1],['a8', 1], ['a9', 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=level_1)
```

Comment: provide your desired output as well

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to categorize them into separate groups

```
df['cat'] = (df['B'].diff() != 0).cumsum()

# filter out the rows/groups you don't want
df = df[df['B'] == 1]
```

output :

```
    A  B  cat
0  a1  1    1
1  a2  1    1
4  a1  1    3
6  a6  1    5
7  a7  1    5
8  a8  1    5
9  a9  1    5
```